# Ability to select time after midnight

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've opening and closing hours select drop-down. This is basically to select opening and closing hours of a shop. I've created the list of hours with 15 min interval from 12:00 Morning to 12:00 Midnight.

```
  $scope.availableTimes = [];
  $scope.availableTimes.push({
    'msValue': 0,
    'display': '12:00 Morning'
  });
  for (var msValue = 900000; msValue <= 85500000; msValue += 900000) { // 90.000ms = 15 min, 85.500.000ms = 11:45PM
    $scope.availableTimes.push({
      'msValue': msValue,
      'display': moment(msValue).utc().format("h:mm A")
    })
  }
  var dayMS = 86400000 - 1;
  $scope.availableTimes.push({
    'msValue': dayMS,
    'display': '12:00 Midnight'
  });
```

But there might be some case they want to select the
 **Opening hour** : 11:00am & **Closing hour**: 2:00am (after midnight) total 15 hours.

To handle this situation `visually` I made a workaround. I rearrange the closing hours based on the opening hour selection.

Example:
If **opening hour** selected as 11:00 am, available **closing hours** will start from 11:15 am upto 10:45 am.

Here the directive to make closing hours list:

```
app.directive('closingTimeSync',function(){
  return {
    template: `<div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Closing Hours</label>
         <select class="form-control" data-ng-options="time.display for time in closingTimes" data-ng-model="selectedToTime">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>`,
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope) {

    scope.automaticallySelectClosingTime = function(msValue) {
     scope.closingTimes = scope.availableTimes;
     var dayMS = 86400000 - 1;
     var remainingTimings = [];
     var index = scope.closingTimes.map(function(obj){return obj.msValue;}).indexOf(msValue);
     index = (index === scope.availableTimes.length-1) ? 1 : index+1;
     scope.closingTimes = scope.closingTimes.slice(index,scope.availableTimes.length);
     if(msValue !== dayMS) {
      remainingTimings = scope.availableTimes.slice(1,index -1);
     }
     scope.closingTimes = scope.closingTimes.concat(remainingTimings);
     scope.selectedToTime = scope.closingTimes[0];
  };
    }
  };
});
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6z58vH86vxi8akl4Pxm3?p=preview)**

**Problem:**
You can see I'm just adding `remainingTimings = scope.availableTimes.slice(1,index -1);`. It gives the ability to select a time after midnight but technically in the millisecond level 2:00 am is less than 11:00 am.

How can I add one extra day in milliseconds if someone selects anything after 12:00 midnight?

Hope I was able to explain clearly.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. The dropdown gives you a time. That time can be made into a datetime or moment object. Then you add the amount of ms that the store has to stay open, so you get the closing time either the same day or the next day. So I don't get why you need to generate two lists. If you work with actual datetimes, adding ms to it will automatically change the date and apply things like daylight savings time. After the calculation, moment can give you the formatted label back.

Comment: In short, I need to give the ability to select opening and closing time. Don't I have to create two lists of time for both fields?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 24 Hours if the closing time is lower than your opening time

Comment: Yes, this is I was trying to do but not sure where I can add the 24 hours.
on `remainingTimings` array? because it creates the hours after midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I would not create lists.
The first list can just be written into the HTML directly, since it will never change.
Or you could create it with a simple angular loop instead of a scope lookup.
Every day starts at 00:00 and ends at 23:59

The second list is just the first list + the amount of time the store is open. And you know that in advance. ( 15 hours )

So I would go for something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <!-- add more options -->
    <option value="23:45">23:45</option>
</select>
```

And for the event handler:

```
function( event ) {
    // Get the selected value in the dropdown.
    const time_chunks = event.target.value.split( ':' );
    // Get the current datetime.
    const opening = new Date();
    // Set the current datetimes hours and minutes to the selected value so opening equals todays opening time.
    opening.setHours( time_chunks[ 0 ] );
    opening.setMinutes( time_chunks[ 1 ] );
    // 3600000 miliseconds = 1 hour
    const hours_open = 15;
    const ms_open = hours_open * 3600000;
    const closing = new Date( opening.getTime() + ms_open );
    // Add code to transform the datetime into the label you need.
    // Add code to save the current state in $scope if needed.
    // Add code to select the correct option in the second dropdown.
}
```

You can probably rewrite the same logic with actual angular and moment methods.

By using actual dates instead of trying to recreate timestamps in a list, you avoid all kinds of timestamp issues like daylight savings time, month barriers on the last day of a month, year barriers on 31 december, etc.

You can use the same principle to generate the lists, if for example, the closing hours don't always have to be 15 hours, **the point is, do all calculations with full datetimes instead of only the times part so the date will actually change to the next day if the closing time is next day**

Comment: Thanks for details explanation. Yes, it's true closing hours not always going to be 15 hours. It may be 8:00 am - 5:00 pm mostly Just for a rare case if someone selects closing hours after midnight How I'm going to determine that closing hour is the next day.

Comment: By using a datetime as i have shown. If you add the current day to the time you have: eg. someone selects 11.00 as opening time. The current full datetime is then `2018-05-24T11:00:00.000Z` ( assuming UTC ) If the store has to stay open 15 hours, the closing datetime is `2018-05-25T02:00:00.000Z` which is basically `2018-05-24T11:00:00.000Z' + 54000000 ms. You have date issues because you ONLY use time in your calculations, not the date.

Comment: Worst case, just divide the new MS total by 3600000 ( one hour ). If it's higher than 24, you know that the closing time is next day.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8oxhWtdY7si8lAdOC7kP?p=preview

See the complete details one what I'm doing.

Comment: You can see Sunday been selected 10:00 am to 2:00:am So when I send the data to server 2:00 am was samller because the way I arranged. But 2:00 should be the milisecound of next day when I send to server.

Comment: I understand the issue, but I already gave you the solution. Change your logic to work with datetimes when you create the second list instead of manually trying to calculate the correct hour by looking for some index. I don't work with angular myself, so I can't write the correct $scope code for you.

Comment: You're looking for something like: `scope.selectedToTime = moment(msValue + 54000000).utc().format("h:mm A")` instead of the array manipulation logic you have. If you do need the array, construct it from this moment object onwards. Or just look at the moment.js documentation. I'm sure there's an easy method to add 15 hours to a moment object.